# Can't install any NPM package, error 4058

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gruntjs

I'm trying to install Grunt on my project. It used to work perfectly, but now for some reason, it does not. Every time i try to install Grunt, I got this error:

```
npm ERR! path C:\irrelevent\path\project\node_modules\ansi-styles
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\irrelevent\path\project\node_modules\ansi-styles' -> 'C:\irrelevent\path\project\.ansi-styles.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-03T00_52_10_105Z-debug.log
```

The weird thing is that the missing package change every time. 
I try verifying the cache, removing the `node_modules` folder, cleaning the cache using `--force`. Uninstall NPM and NodeJS, restart my computer. No chances.
I had to format my computer for security reason, I took the project folder but not the `Roaming` folder, I don't know if this had an impact, but it shouldn't since I reinstalled NPM.

I'm not sure if this will help but here is my `package.json`

```
{
 "name": "project",
 "version": "2.1.0",
 "repository": "project-2.0",
 "devDependencies": {
   "grunt": "^1.0.2",
   "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
   "grunt-contrib-concat": "~1.0.1",
   "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
   "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~2.0.0",
   "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~1.1.0",
   "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~2.2.0",
   "grunt-contrib-watch": "~1.0.0",
   "grunt-html-build": "^0.7.1",
   "grunt-real-favicon": "^0.2.2"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "angular-bootstrap-colorpicker": "^3.0.31",
   "angularjs-geolocation": "^0.1.3",
   "sprintf-js": "^1.1.1"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try these steps:

- Delete `package-lock.json` and run NPM again.
- Ensure no other processes of node.js are running (check task manager)
- If you are using visual studio code, close it and try running `npm install` again.
- If all else fails, restart your computer.

See thread here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17444

Comment: unfortunately this did not work. I tried removed the `package-lock.json` (there was none), there was no Node.Js process running. I closed PHPstorm ( i don't use VSCode ) And still had the error. I even try to uninstall NodeJS and delete the folder in Roaming.

Comment: Turns out it was Malwarebytes fault. Thanks for pointing me to the right thread.

Answer (score 9):

While using `npx create-next-app`, we got this error saying, that lstat on a directory couldn't be used, because it doesn't exists:

```
C:\someDirectory\> npx create-next-app@latest
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     %userprofile%\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\[TimeStamp]-debug-0.log
```

The mentioned solutions didn't help, it was just required to create the directory `npm` under `%appdata%`.

The installer just checked for it, but did not create it and therefor raised the error.

Answer (score 8):

For me the reason was Dropbox (my NodeJS project being somewhere deep in the Dropbox folder). I suspended the synchronisation, tried `npm install` again and it installed without error. Then of course I resumed the synchronisation.

Answer (score 6):

you should not forget to goto the project folder by `cd "nameofproject"` and then `"npm start"` is work.

Answer (score 3):

- delete package-lock.josn and node_modules
- clear npm cache by `npm cache clear --force`
- restart VS Code
- running `npm install`again

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Check if you have created an inside folder with the same folder name.
2. If 2 folders exist with the same name (Delete that 1st folder)
3. Go to terminal: `npm start`

Answer (score 1):

To solve this error for VS-Code:

1. Close VS-Code
2. Perform `npm cache clear --force`
3. Restart VS-Code.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, mine is resolved with the help of changing directory (cd frontend) as my project structure was js>frontend>src>index.html

before running npm start, make sure you are in the right directory.

**solution**

1. cd frontend (your directory name)
2. npm start

I installed (npm install -D live-server) and
in package.json, I set "start" command as
"start":"live-server src--verbose"

Answer (score 1):

I tried many things like installing different versions , clearing cache , editing environmental variable but nothing works , then on rather than installing nodejs i just extract files of nodejs and it works in my case.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30903570)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved this error.
npm audit --force.

Answer (score 1):

Before you run `npx create-react-app <react-project>` perform:

```
mkdir C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Comment: Hello @Lamanti7. Is your answer intended as a solution specifically for the issue raised in the original question, or you meant to say that people trying to run ```npx create-react-app``` may also run into a similar error and your answer presents a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple things but in the end, I just had to update npm to the latest version with this command.

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

After that everything continued to work smoothly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34994104)