# Getting Error ENOENT - 4058 While running 'npm run dev' command using VScode on windows machine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

While trying to run `npm run dev` command on *VScode* to kickstart a **REACT** project. The Error **ENOENT - 4058** won't let me progress.

I've tried to remove the `package-lock.json`, I also tried to re-install the ***npm*** and even turned off my antivirus while restarting my PC...

None of this worked.

Comment: Can you provide more information? The full text of the error would be helpful. In addition, the 'scripts' section from the package.json file can be useful.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620780/cant-install-any-npm-package-error-4058 . Please check

Comment: possible duplicate of *  @PrakashP , we're not entirely sure its a duplicate.