# I can't run npm start

Tags: node.js, npm

I have created successfuly created a react app using npx create-react-app but when I type npm start, it flags error

```
npm start

The error is: 
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Gerald\Documents\profile\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Gerald\Documents\profile\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Gerald\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-19T08_31_34_664Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620780/cant-install-any-npm-package-error-4058

Answer (score 2):

You first need to navigate to the folder where you created your app.