# Getting ENOENT error when running "npm start" for React apps

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, enoent

I have been shifting between node versions 10.17.0 and 16.14.0(the latest version) since I work with SharePoint Framework which only supports node version 10.x.x. Now I have shifted back to the latest node version but when trying to run any of my React apps with the command npm start, I am facing with this error:

[image]

I have tried everything like uninstalling and reinstalling node on my computer, removing node_modules and package-lock.json files and doing npm install command but still get the error when trying to run my app with npm start.

Same problem applies whether I run npm start in windows cmd or Visual Studio Codes terminal.

Do you guys have any suggestion on what I should do?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: I have tried everything like as Abbas Hussain said and also uninstalling and reinstalling Node but I am still facing this error.**

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. There was a problem with the bash file so I did this in cmd:

```
npm config set script-shell "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"
```

And reinstalled node and npm so after that it worked fine!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I think I have faced a similar issue before the step that I follow

- delete `/node_modules`
- delete `package-lock.json` or `yarn-lock.json`
- run this command `npm cache clean --force` or `yarn cache clean`
- `npm install` or `yarn`

Hope this will resolve your issue

Comment: Abbas Hussain, I have tried that but it did not work for me. It gives me the same error when I come to npm install

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17444#issuecomment-311522791
maybe this is problem try to close all the node task and then follow above commands.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49620827/10939373

Comment: I have tried everything here but no luck

Comment: I even tried creating a new react app now but even that gives me the same error. I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: I have also added "C:\Program Files\nodejs\" to PATH field in my environment variables but still getting the same error.

Comment: I had NVM installed on my computer and have understood that all node related files end up in NVM folder so I uninstalled NVM, uninstalled Node and NPM and the reinstalled Node and NPM but still get the same error. Help me, this is driving me crazy!