# I cant create an react app in my local computer

Tags: reactjs

i can't create an React app,i have installed node latest version,eventhough it shows error like this ,can any one find solution for this.
error on terminal : no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\kowsh\AppData\Roaming\npm'                                                              [error msg while creating the react app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwCh2.png)

Comment: Add error messages as text not as image. Did you take a look into the logfile?

Answer (score 2):

[Refer to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620780/cant-install-any-npm-package-error-4058%20Try%20these%20steps.)

To solve your problem.

1. Delete package-lock.json and run NPM again.
2. Ensure no other processes of node.js are running (check task manager)
3. If you are using visual studio code, close it and try running npm install again.
4. If all else fails, restart your computer.

This is the answer in above link you can try it.

Comment: how to delet that package-lock.json