# I am getting a lot of error while trying to build a new react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-hooks

I am new to React, and while trying to create an app on VS Code but I am unable to do so and I getting the following error:-
[image]

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong, I have already installed node.js and npm and they have been installed successfully.

Comment: try to reinstalll or update node and npm

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49620780/9778302