# There is no directory while installing react server

Tags: reactjs, npm

```
const result = binding.mkdir(
                         ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'D:\interview tasks react\adwinreact'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1373:26)
    at module.exports.makeDirSync (C:\Users\Mahe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\make-dir.js:23:13)
    at createApp (C:\Users\Mahe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:257:6)
    at C:\Users\Mahe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:223:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: 'D:\\interview tasks react\\adwinreact'
}
```

What to do to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

#### Possible solutions:

1. Try deleting `package-lock.json` and run NPM again.
2. Make sure no other instances of NodeJS are running.
3. Make sure file system permissions are properly configured.
4. Close the editor and run:
   `npm cache clear --force`
   wait for the process to finish.
5. At last resort a machine restart may be of help.

Referencing similar issue:
[Can't install any NPM package, error 4058](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620780/cant-install-any-npm-package-error-4058)